# How to access JBOSS Restful web service using IP and Port

Tags: eclipse, web-services, rest, jboss

I created  a test JBOSS web service and there is only one test method in it. I access this using `http://localhost:8070/MyWebService/MyRESTApplication`
and it shows the result from the web service. I tried this in both Eclipse and Browser and it works.

But when i want to access this web service using IP address of my system then it shows ERROR message that Page cannot be displayed (in fact browser is not able to find this web service).

I want to access like this `http://IPaddress:8070/MyWebService/MyRESTApplication`
what should i do so that i can access it using my IP from some computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your server setting in Eclipse and set Host name as your IP address or 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

You have to start JBoss using :

```
./run.sh -b [your_IPaddress]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I think your solution is for Linux but I am using Windows

Comment: Ok for Windows it's the same thing with run.bat (in the bin directory)

Answer (score 2):

On windows:

```
start run.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

This will tell it to start and bind to all network interfaces.  You can also replace 0.0.0.0 with your actual IP if you only want it to bind to that network interface.

I find it easier for debugging to have it come up on all network interfaces because this will work when you are running a virtual machine to debug something like Internet Explorer.

Comment: I have tried this and also the above solution from @alain.janinm but when i run the command it is executed but stuck on this step saying waiting to obtain Lock.what should i do..

Comment: perhaps you are in Windows 7?  You might need to run it as administrator in order for windows to give up permission to the network interface.  Try putting it in a .bat or .cmd file and then right click on it and Run as Administrator.

Comment: @WaseemKhan If j4y solution doesn't work edit your question and add the log it can help us. Thanks.

Comment: I have done this by setting 0.0.0.0 in Server configuration of JBOSS server by setting Hostname as 0.0.0.0 and now it is working for me. Thanks